# How to setup Amd gpu for Arch Linux and Activate it for processing?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, gpu, amd-graphics

I am on manajaro linux with KDE desktop enviroment i tired a lot but i can't get working with my amd gpu drivers for the processing and display controlling 
here is my `lspci` logs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host     
Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen                     
Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem    
(rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C  
Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C 
Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev     
21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7     
M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile] (rev c3)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast 
Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

output of `xrandr --listproviders`

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink      
Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0xa8 cap: 0xd, Source Output, Source Offload, Sink   
Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:Unknown AMD  
Radeon GPU @ pci:0000:01:00.0
```

and output of `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
```

also the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display|3D'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 
(rev 02)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
  --
  01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
 Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 
  620/625 Mobile] (rev c3)
    Subsystem: Dell Radeon R7 M445
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

i tired a lot for this and when i use  any graphics related software always uses intel cpu for processing.My laptop is DELL 5567. please help me to solve this issue 
Note :- my gpu is Amd radeon r7 m445

Comment: Please provide output of following commands in your question `xrandr --listproviders` and `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`

Comment: @binarysta i have updated my question please review it

Comment: well lets do a test first, please run `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 1 0` then `DRI_PRIME=1` and again check `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`.

Comment: also please, in the question replace your `lspci` output with `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display|3D'` output. since need to know which kernel drivers are being used.

Comment: @binarysta i have update it and glxinfo output is showing intel graphics in use